# problem in Retrieving rich text box sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need to retrieve values from a rich text box from a list.My code till now is this..

```
        ArrayList arCategory=new ArrayList();               
        SPList myList = myWeb.Lists["PList"]; 
        SPQuery myQuery = new SPQuery();
        myQuery.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ProgramID' Ascending="False"/></OrderBy>;

            SPListItemCollection myItemCol = myList.GetItems(myQuery);

            foreach (SPListItem myItem in myItemCol)
            {                   
                string strCatTxt = (string)myItem["Category"];-->
```

//Category is the multiline rich text column

```
              arCategory.Add(strCatTxt);
            }

           for (int j = 0; j < arCategory.Count; j++)
          {
          Label lblCategory = new Label();
          lblCategory.Text=arCategory[j].Tostring(); ---->Getting exception
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not SharePoint here. In your code, you have `lblCategory.Text=arCategory[j].Tostring();`

If `arCategory[j]` is `null`, you get an exception when you call ToString() on it.

So basically you can fix it like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < arCategory.Count; j++) {
  if (arCategory[j]!=null){
    Label lblCategory = new Label();
    lblCategory.Text=arCategory[j].Tostring(); ---->Getting exception
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Or, of course, you could add a `<Where>...` element in your query and read only values from the items which have Category different from `null`. This will also make your query execute faster!